# iOS native keyboard appearance does not automatically change when system dark mode is turn on/off

Tags: flutter, darkmode

I implemented dark mode with both system (automatic) and manual (on/off) in my Flutter app and almost everything works fine.

However, under the system (automatic) mode. When a TextField is focused and the system appearance change (eg from System Light to System Dark and vice versa), the iOS native keyboard appearance doesn't change immediately until I unfocused and focused again the same TextField, or focus on other TextField, then it only changed.

I tried to set `Brightness` in `ThemeData` use `keyboardAppearance` in the TextField, it doesn't work.

```
final lightTheme = ThemeData(
  brightness: Brightness.light,
);

final darkTheme = ThemeData(
  brightness: Brightness.dark,
);

TextFormField(
 keyboardAppearance: Theme.of(context).brightness
)
```

Here's my screenshot attached below:

[Keyboard appearance after system changed from light to dark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HUOc.png)

[Keyboard appearance after system changed from dark to light](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88w4v.png)

My Flutter version: 3.7.2.